# To check if a given string contains a substring without using contains or indexOf method

Tags: java

In the following code the problem I am facing is how to make the inner loop start from a given index instead of 0 every time.

LOGIC:

```
substr = rohan; 
mainstr = herohanda
```

The code first check the first character of `substr` i.e `'r'` with every character of `mainstr` till it finds a match. When a match is found the program return to the outer loop and increments `i` to check if the 2nd charcater of `substr` (i.e `o`) matches the next character(the character next to the index where a match for `'r'` was found) of the `mainStr`. The problem is how to start the inner loop from that next character. Here it is starting with the initial index (0) each time  .

CODE:

```
public class SubstringInString {
   public static void isSubstring(String subStr, String mainStr){
         int flag = 0;
         int counter = 0;
        OUTER: for(int i = flag; i<subStr.length(); i = i+flag){
            INNER:  for(int j = 0; j< mainStr.length(); j=counter ){
                        if(subStr.charAt(i) == mainStr.charAt(j)){
                            counter++;
                            flag++;

                            continue OUTER;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if((mainStr.length() - i) >= subStr.length()){
                                counter ++;
                                flag = 0;

                                continue INNER;
                            }

                            else{
                                System.out.println("Main String does not contain the substring");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            //  System.out.println("Match found at " + j-subStr.length());
        }
}
```

Please tell me what how to solve this and also if there is any better way to do the same.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we want to find out if `s2` is a substring of `s1`.

There are 2 base cases:

1. length of `s2` is 0: In this case, we can return `true`.
2. length of `s2` is more than that of `s1`: We can return `false`.

The general approach is as follows: Iterate through each character of `s1` and see if it matches with the first character of `s2`. If it does, then check if rest of the characters of `s1` match with rest of the characters of `s2`. If so, return `true`. If the `s1` is entirely explored with no matches found, return `false`.

Here is how it would look like in Java:

```
static boolean isSubstring(String s1, String s2){
    int n1 = s1.length();
    int n2 = s2.length();

    if(n2 == 0)     // Base Case 1
        return true;

    if(n2 > n1)    // Base Case 2
        return false;

    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
        if(s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(0))        // if first char matches
            if(isRestMatch(i+1, s1, s2))       // check if rest match
                return true;

    return false;
}

static boolean isRestMatch(int start, String s1, String s2){
    int n = s2.length();
    for(int i = start, x = 1; i < n; i++, x++)
        if(s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(x))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Long time ago, but this only works if s2 is different in the first or second character of the string. For s1 = "hwegnwieu" and s2 = "wee" it gives true.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this solves the problem:

```
public static void isSubstring(String subStr, String mainStr){
    return mainStr.matches(".*\\Q" + subStr + "\\E.*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this Java implementation](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/leetcode-implement-strstr-java/)

```
public String strStr(String haystack, String needle) {

    int needleLen = needle.length();
    int haystackLen = haystack.length();

    if (needleLen == haystackLen && needleLen == 0)
        return "";

    if (needleLen == 0)
        return haystack;

    for (int i = 0; i < haystackLen; i++) {
        // make sure in boundary of needle
        if (haystackLen - i + 1 < needleLen)
            return null;

        int k = i;
        int j = 0;

        while (j < needleLen && k < haystackLen && needle.charAt(j) == haystack.charAt(k)) {
            j++;
            k++;
            if (j == needleLen)
                return haystack.substring(i);
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```